# MongoDB aggregation pipeline with $lookup and $match is very slow

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use mongoDb aggregation pipeline to lookup other table and check if matched some of the attributes.

my query is something like below (p.s. bigtable is sharded):

```
 db.bigtable.aggregate( [  
    {$lookup:{ from: "user", localField:
               "user_code", foreignField: "code",as: "user"}},   
    {$match: {"user.country":"US" } }] )
```

I have created index for bigtable.user_code, user.code & user.country. But the query is very very very slow. I tried explain it, it is COLLSCAN.

Do you know if index is not supported in $match with foreign table?

Comment: Why not run the aggregate pipeline on the `user` collection where you can put appropriate indexes e.g. on the `country` field and then do a lookup to the other collection `bigtable` on the filtered documents i.e. `db.user.aggregate( [  {$match: {"country":"US" } }
    {$lookup:{ from: "bigtable", localField:
               "code", foreignField: "user_code",as: "bigtable"}},   
    ] )`?

Comment: bigtable is in shard, therefore, it can't be used in the lookup as foreign table

Comment: Can you show what the explain tells you?